# Using tar -zcvf against a folder creates an empty compressed file

Tags: linux, compression, cloud, server, tar

I am ssh'ed into an Acquia server trying to download some files. I need to backup these files for local development (to get user uploaded images mainly).

I am using the following command:

```
tar -zcvf ~/download/stage-files_3-19-2015_1344.tar.gz files/
```

I have read/write access to the download folder. I created that folder. I am in the parent folder of "files". And permissions to that folder are 777.

I was able to run this the other day with no issues. So I am very confused as to why this is happening now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just figured this darn thing out. Must have run out of disk space because once I removed a prior compressed backup of the files it started running just fine. Dang disk quotas. Sorry guys.